# Xcode Python - Too many levels of symbolic links

Tags: python-3.x, macos, homebrew, symlink, xcode12

Was attempting to set up Xcode for python dev just because and I ran into an issue.

I followed this tutorial: [Run Python Code in XCode 10! (2018)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h8_68OONY-w)
While the UI is a bit different in the initial creation of the project I was able to find what I was looking for.

path to python3: `/usr/bin/python3`

After following the instruction and running the code I ran into this error:

```
2021-08-10 14:20:54.227437-0500 python3[5828:364044] Failed to open macho file at /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/python3 for reading: Too many levels of symbolic links
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/python3: can't open file 'testingPython.py': [Errno 1] Operation not permitted
Program ended with exit code: 2
```

I checked the /usr/bin dir and I didn't see anything representing a symlink for python3

```
lrwxr-xr-x     1 root   wheel        74 Jan  1  2020 pydoc -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/pydoc2.7
lrwxr-xr-x     1 root   wheel        74 Jan  1  2020 pydoc2.7 -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/pydoc2.7
lrwxr-xr-x     1 root   wheel        75 Jan  1  2020 python -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7
lrwxr-xr-x     1 root   wheel        82 Jan  1  2020 python-config -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7-config
lrwxr-xr-x     1 root   wheel        75 Jan  1  2020 python2 -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7
lrwxr-xr-x     1 root   wheel        75 Jan  1  2020 python2.7 -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7
lrwxr-xr-x     1 root   wheel        82 Jan  1  2020 python2.7-config -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7-config
-rwxr-xr-x     1 root   wheel    137616 Jan  1  2020 python3
lrwxr-xr-x     1 root   wheel        76 Jan  1  2020 pythonw -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/pythonw2.7
lrwxr-xr-x     1 root   wheel        76 Jan  1  2020 pythonw2.7 -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/pythonw2.7
```

so I decided to check Homebrew: `brew info python3`

and got this:

```
python@3.9: stable 3.9.5 (bottled)
Interpreted, interactive, object-oriented programming language
https://www.python.org/
Not installed
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/HEAD/Formula/python@3.9.rb
License: Python-2.0
==> Dependencies
Build: pkg-config ✘
Required: gdbm ✘, mpdecimal ✘, openssl@1.1 ✔, readline ✘, sqlite ✘, xz ✘
==> Caveats
Python has been installed as
  /opt/homebrew/bin/python3

Unversioned symlinks `python`, `python-config`, `pip` etc. pointing to
`python3`, `python3-config`, `pip3` etc., respectively, have been installed into
  /opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.9/libexec/bin

You can install Python packages with
  pip3 install <package>
They will install into the site-package directory
  /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages

tkinter is no longer included with this formula, but it is available separately:
  brew install python-tk@3.9

See: https://docs.brew.sh/Homebrew-and-Python
```

it mentioned not being installed so I tried reinstalling and got a warning:

```
Warning: The post-install step did not complete successfully
You can try again using:
  brew postinstall python@3.9
```

So I tried the post-install and got the same response

So I went in and manually deleted all of Homebrew's symlinks for python3 from `/opt/homebrew.bin` and the entire folder `/opt/homebrew/python@3.9`

Ran build again and got the same error output

reinstalled python3: `brew install python3`

```
Updating Homebrew...
==> Auto-updated Homebrew!
Updated 1 tap (homebrew/core).
==> Updated Formulae
Updated 2 formulae.

==> Downloading https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core/python/3.9/manifests/3.9.6
Already downloaded: /Users/dmconklin/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/497333c6ca5bfe88a2fd95008a6b111ac766162ed5900db38c7529dbd33e2859--python@3.9-3.9.6.bottle_manifest.json
==> Downloading https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core/python/3.9/blobs/sha256:36bdb8151cdc242487b9d3e6d6f305057b5699b4f6ac6905fc875e11b4ac2f3b
Already downloaded: /Users/dmconklin/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/19520443760763aaa669f5ffeafb108cb2ba3b2b10f674bc4dc179b05f30ef3f--python@3.9--3.9.6.arm64_big_sur.bottle.tar.gz
==> Pouring python@3.9--3.9.6.arm64_big_sur.bottle.tar.gz
Warning: This keg was marked linked already, continuing anyway
==> /opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.6/bin/python3 -m ensurepip
==> /opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.6/bin/python3 -m pip install -v --no-deps --no-index --upgrade --isolated --target=/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages /opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.6/Frameworks/Python
==> Caveats
Python has been installed as
  /opt/homebrew/bin/python3

Unversioned symlinks `python`, `python-config`, `pip` etc. pointing to
`python3`, `python3-config`, `pip3` etc., respectively, have been installed into
  /opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.9/libexec/bin

You can install Python packages with
  pip3 install <package>
They will install into the site-package directory
  /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages

tkinter is no longer included with this formula, but it is available separately:
  brew install python-tk@3.9

See: https://docs.brew.sh/Homebrew-and-Python
==> Summary
  /opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.6: 3,080 files, 56.5MB
```

`brew info python3`

```
python@3.9: stable 3.9.6 (bottled)
Interpreted, interactive, object-oriented programming language
https://www.python.org/
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.6 (3,080 files, 56.5MB) *
  Poured from bottle on 2021-08-10 at 15:29:26
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/HEAD/Formula/python@3.9.rb
License: Python-2.0
==> Dependencies
Build: pkg-config ✘
Required: gdbm ✔, mpdecimal ✔, openssl@1.1 ✔, readline ✔, sqlite ✔, xz ✔
==> Caveats
Python has been installed as
  /opt/homebrew/bin/python3

Unversioned symlinks `python`, `python-config`, `pip` etc. pointing to
`python3`, `python3-config`, `pip3` etc., respectively, have been installed into
  /opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.9/libexec/bin

You can install Python packages with
  pip3 install <package>
They will install into the site-package directory
  /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages

tkinter is no longer included with this formula, but it is available separately:
  brew install python-tk@3.9

See: https://docs.brew.sh/Homebrew-and-Python
```

and after that I still have the same error about too many levels of symbolic links

I'm not sure what else to do or where to look.

found:

```
lrwxr-xr-x   1 dmconklin  admin      8 Jun 28 03:57 2to3 -> 2to3-3.9
-rwxr-xr-x   1 dmconklin  admin    169 Aug 10 15:29 2to3-3.9
lrwxr-xr-x   1 dmconklin  admin      7 Jun 28 03:57 idle3 -> idle3.9
-rwxr-xr-x   1 dmconklin  admin    167 Aug 10 15:29 idle3.9
-rwxr-xr-x   1 dmconklin  admin    247 Aug 10 15:29 pip3
-rwxr-xr-x   1 dmconklin  admin    247 Aug 10 15:29 pip3.9
lrwxr-xr-x   1 dmconklin  admin      8 Jun 28 03:57 pydoc3 -> pydoc3.9
-rwxr-xr-x   1 dmconklin  admin    152 Aug 10 15:29 pydoc3.9
lrwxr-xr-x   1 dmconklin  admin      9 Jun 28 03:57 python3 -> python3.9
lrwxr-xr-x   1 dmconklin  admin     16 Jun 28 03:57 python3-config -> python3.9-config
-rwxr-xr-x   1 dmconklin  admin  69168 Aug 10 15:29 python3.9
-rwxr-xr-x   1 dmconklin  admin   2111 Aug 10 15:29 python3.9-config
```

in: `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin`

I tried to using that file path directly to python3.9 instead of python3 in `/usr/bin/` and still get the same output in Xcode

[Xcode Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yi9cS.png)
also tried this
[Xcode Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5H9TB.png)

same result, too many levels of symlinks

also note that python3 isn't accessible when editing the scheme

[/opt/homebrew/bin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OrcfQ.png)
[/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JYGq9.png)

Comment: Find the setting that shows the actual path to your `python3` executable and change it from `/usr/bin/python3` to `/opt/homebrew/bin/python3`. Does that help? `/usr/bin/python3` is the system version of Python. You want the Homebrew version.

Comment: @MattDMo it did not

Comment: @MattDMo @DMConklin macOS is not Linux. Don't ever touch `/usr/bin/`. In fact you can't links things into there unless SIP is disabled.

Comment: @Simba I never suggested messing with `/usr/bin`. All I said was they should change the python interpreter path in the XCode settings. I've been using OSX/macOS for over a decade, I know about `/usr/bin`. To your point, though, if you *do* need to have new system-wide binaries or links, `/usr/local/bin` is the place to go.

Answer (score 1):

I also met this problem.
I created a link to python3 in /opt/homebrew/bin folder, and solved this alert.

```
cd /opt/homebrew/bin
ln python3 xcodePython3  // any name you'd like to use
```

Then in "Edit Scheme", select "Executable" to the /opt/homebrew/bin folder, and select xcodePython3.

Comment: This works! Not using homebrew so my binary path is:

cd /usr/local/bin
ln python3 xcodePython3

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for solution in a wrong direction.

1. `/usr/bin/python3` never existed, even shipping of `/usr/bin/python2` will be dropped out of macOS in a future macOS release. Installing python with `pyenv` or `conda` is recommended.
2. You messed up Python in homebrew. Homebrew package `python` is designed to serve as a dependency for other brewed packages. The default linked python package should be `python` but not a versioned on like `python@3.9`.

   ```sh
   brew unlink python@3.9
   brew install python
   brew link python # this may be unneeded, run it anyway
   ```

For your project, if you need python3, choose `/opt/homebrew/bin/python3`. But for a big project with many third-party python packages, use a virtual environment.

BTW, you guys code python with Xcode? Switch to VSCode or Pycharm.

Comment: I had already reinstalled python after I removed the folders. ```brew install python``` is the same as ```brew install python3``` Also ```/opt/homebrew/bin/python3``` is not a selectable executable when editing the scheme nor does the path produce any results when adding it to the build tool field under ```External Build Tool Configuration``` I do normally use VSCode for python, this was just something I wanted to see if I could get working for the future when I finally got on it and learned swift lol